# XADES-A implementation in Java with manually entered signature value

Tags: digital-signature, signature, xml-dsig, xades

I am trying to implement XADES-A by using signature value manually. Is there any sample examples. I found several examples for XADES-BES and XADES-EPES. But didn't get any example git repo or any other guide for XADES-A. Can someone please help me on this one?

I implemented XADES_BES in java, I can't extend it to XADES_A as there are fields such as ArchiveTimeStamp, RevocationValues. As final output I want to implement XADES-A using signature value manually.